# Ejercicio de lista enlazada en C (RADIO)

Tags: c

Estoy intentando hacer un ejercicio en C de listas enlazadas en el cual primero creo una estructura persona y luego hago otra locutor la cual tendrá una estructura persona. Para hacer los registros utilizo una lista.

El problema está en que me deja hacer un registro y lo imprime pero cuando quiero hacer algún otro registro entra en la condición en la que no se puede reservar memoria y no sé por qué.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct persona {
    int edad;
    char *nombre;
    int cedula;
    struct persona *sig;
} Persona;

typedef struct locutor {
    Persona persona_locutor;
    struct locutor *sig;
} Locutor;

//INICIALIZAR LA LISTA
Locutor *inicializarListaLocutor(Locutor *cabeza_de_lista) {
    return cabeza_de_lista=NULL;
}

Locutor * crearLocutor() {

    //CREANDO EL Locutor
    Locutor *registroNuevo;
    registroNuevo=(Locutor*)malloc(sizeof(Locutor));

    //SINO SE PUDO RESERVAR MEMORIA PARA EL REGISTRO
    if(!registroNuevo) {
        printf("No se pudo crear memoria para el registro\n");

    return NULL;
    } else {
        //SI SE PUDO RESERVAR LA MEMORIA SE INSERTAN LOS DATOS
        printf("Ingrese el nombre del nuevo locutor: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(registroNuevo->persona_locutor.nombre);
        printf("Ingrese la edad del nuevo locutor: ");
        scanf("%i", &registroNuevo->persona_locutor.edad);
        printf("Ingrese la cedula del nuevo locutor: ");
        scanf("%i", &registroNuevo->persona_locutor.cedula);
        registroNuevo->sig=NULL;
    }

    return registroNuevo;
}


Locutor *insertarEnListaLocutores(Locutor *cabeza_de_lista)
{
    Locutor *cabeza_de_listaAuxiliar ,*registroNuevo;
    registroNuevo = crearLocutor();

    //SI SE PUDO CREAR EL Locutor QUE SE INSERTE EN LA LISTA
    if(registroNuevo)
    {
        //SI LA LISTA ESTA VACIA
        if(!cabeza_de_lista)
            cabeza_de_lista = registroNuevo;
        else {
            //SE USA EL cabeza_de_lista AUXILIAR PARA MOVERSE ENTRE LOS LocutorS
            cabeza_de_listaAuxiliar = cabeza_de_lista;
            while(cabeza_de_listaAuxiliar->sig)
                cabeza_de_listaAuxiliar = cabeza_de_listaAuxiliar->sig;
            cabeza_de_listaAuxiliar->sig=registroNuevo;
        }
    }

    return cabeza_de_lista;
}

void imprimirListaLocutor(Locutor * cabeza_de_lista)
{
    Locutor *cabeza_de_listaAuxiliar;
    cabeza_de_listaAuxiliar = cabeza_de_lista;

    while(cabeza_de_listaAuxiliar)
    {
        printf("El nombre del locutor es:%s \n", cabeza_de_listaAuxiliar->persona_locutor.nombre);
        printf("La edad del locutor es:%d \n", cabeza_de_listaAuxiliar->persona_locutor.edad);
        printf("La cedula del locutor es:%d \n", cabeza_de_listaAuxiliar->persona_locutor.cedula);
        cabeza_de_listaAuxiliar = cabeza_de_listaAuxiliar->sig;
    }
    printf("\n");

}

int main ()
{

     Locutor *cabeza_de_lista_locutor;

     cabeza_de_lista_locutor = inicializarListaLocutor(cabeza_de_lista_locutor);
     cabeza_de_lista_locutor = insertarEnListaLocutores(cabeza_de_lista_locutor);
     cabeza_de_lista_locutor = insertarEnListaLocutores(cabeza_de_lista_locutor);
     cabeza_de_lista_locutor = insertarEnListaLocutores(cabeza_de_lista_locutor);

     imprimirListaLocutor(cabeza_de_lista_locutor);
     printf("\n");
     free(cabeza_de_lista_locutor);

     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 Locutor *cabeza_de_lista_locutor;

 cabeza_de_lista_locutor = inicializarListaLocutor(cabeza_de_lista_locutor);
```

En esa primera llamada a `inicializarListaLocutor`, ¿A dónde dirías que apunta `cabeza_de_lista_locutor`? La respuesta correcta es: a una posición de memoria aleatoria.

¿Qué hace la función entonces?

```
Locutor *insertarEnListaLocutores(Locutor *cabeza_de_lista)
{
    if(registroNuevo)
    {
        //SI LA LISTA ESTA VACIA
        if(!cabeza_de_lista)
            cabeza_de_lista = registroNuevo;
        else
          // ...
    }

    return cabeza_de_lista;
}
```

Básicamente, como `cabeza_de_lista` no es NULL entenderá que la lista ya tiene elementos y simplemente añadirá los elementos. El problema aquí es que en la primera llamada la lista **no existe**.

La solución es tan sencilla como inicializar `cabeza_de_lista_locutor`:

```
Locutor *cabeza_de_lista_locutor = 0; /* o NULL, como prefieras */

cabeza_de_lista_locutor = inicializarListaLocutor(cabeza_de_lista_locutor);
```

Por otro lado, la estructura `Persona` no debería tener el puntero `sig`. Primero porque no lo usas y segundo porque dentro `Locutor` puede provocar problemas: Si una función recibe un puntero de tipo `Persona`, ¿debe tener en cuenta el puntero sig?

Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta